# Nunit for C dll

Tags: c#, c, dll, nunit-3.0

I have created a dll using C code, which exports a structure as below in Visual Studio Professional 2013,

```
#define _export __declspec( dllexport )

typedef struct{
struct_member1;
struct_member2;
#include "myheader.h"
struct_member3;
struct_member4;
..
.
}MY_STRUCT

_export MY_STRUCT myStruct;
```

Where as **myheader.h** contains declarations for some function pointers.

```
return_type (*myfun1)(arg1, arg2, ...);
return_type (*myfun2)(arg1, arg2, ...);
..
.
```

In C# Nunit framework am able load the dll and access to myStruct structure using

```
dll_handler = UnsafeNativeMethods.LoadLibrary(dll_path);
struct_handler = UnsafeNativeMethods.GetProcAddress(DllHandler, "myStruct");
```

Now am struggling to access those function pointer declared in **myheader.h** using the struct_handler in C#.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

JAI.

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with NUnit. Your question is a generic interop question of the "how do I marshal this struct to C#" variety. Which, by the way, is not something you want to do if it can be avoided, due to those nasty embedded function pointers. Is the definition of the DLL a given or is it wrappable? In general you're much better off using C++/CLI or COM to wrap code like this for managed consumption, rather than have C# call it directly. You aren't using NUnit just so you can unit test this, right? C has its own unit testing solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I have a C dll (prepared out of pure C code), I want to unit test it using Nunit.    Can you suggest the better way to proceed further.

Comment: There's a ton of native C options, many of them xUnit compatible. [Take your pick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C). If for some unholy reason you *must* use NUnit, you're still better off writing some C++/CLI to expose things as managed code. But this is folly, because you are introducing a real risk that your tests themselves will be buggy due to bad interop. It's a classic "square peg in a round hole" approach.